# Поддержка стабильного интернет-соединения

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Столкнулся с проблемой постоянного стабильного интернет-соединения на Android.

Особенно эта проблема появляется при отключении вай-фая или же при мобильном интернете, но нужно же постоянно при возможности проверять, есть ли новые данные, и загружать их на устройство.

Также нужно сразу после того как интернет появится, чтобы сразу все загружалось. Еще есть проблема с тем, что бывает просто зависает запрос и ничего не происходит, просто висит.

Я все делаю циклом и интервалом подключения, т.е. постоянно отправляю запросы, когда есть сеть и когда ее нет. А также устанавливаю, что запрос может быть не дольше 30 секунд.

Есть решения получше?

Comment: Уменьшить время ожидания. У меня обычно 10 секунд стоит, не более.

Comment: @Suvitruf дело в том, что у меня длинные запросы. Т.е. сервер может держать его около 30 секунд, если нет новой информации, то просто останавливает выполнения скрипта. Я слышал, что можно на одном запросе держать создавать более чем один запрос и поддерживать соединение, но не знаю, как это сделать. Как у Вас все работает?

Comment: @M11 а для чего вам long pooling? Чат, что ли, пишете?

Comment: @Suvitruf приложение для соцсети